# How to add email blacklist option in django-allauth?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

The [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) package has a settings variable **`ACCOUNT_USERNAME_BLACKLIST`** that can be used to restrict the usage of usernames. In a similar way, how can I add a ***`ACCOUNT_EMAIL_BLACKLIST`*** settings variable that holds a list of blocked emails to the application?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a custom account adapter

```py
# utils/adapter.py

from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings


class CustomAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def clean_email(self, email):
        if email in settings.ACCOUNT_EMAIL_BLACKLIST:
            raise forms.ValidationError(f"{email} has been blacklisted")
        return super().clean_email(email)
```

Then, change the [**`ACCOUNT_ADAPTER`**](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) settings value

```py
# settings.py

ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "utils.adapter.CustomAccountAdapter"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_BLACKLIST = ["someemail.test.com"]
```

Comment: thanks for replay when i apply these it show this error

Comment: AttributeError at /accounts/signup/
module 'allauth.account.adapter' has no attribute 'CustomAccountAdapter'

Comment: It seems you have given the wrong pathname value for ***`ACCOUNT_ADAPTER`***

Comment: can you explain to me how to add the pathname please

Comment: I have already given example in this answer

Comment: yes i can see that .. the problem is i have already adapter.py file inside account folder and i have class called DefaultAccountAdapter and inside DefaultAccountAdapter class i have def clean_email(self, email): okay so i don't know what i must edit or where i can add you code